# If G is k-vertex-connected then G-v is k-1-connected

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Prove that if $G$ is k-vertex-connected then for every $v$ in $V(G)$, $G-V$ is (k-1)-vertex connected.
I will appreciate any hints.

Comment: Hint: what is the definition of $k$-vertex-connected?

Comment: A graph is k-vertex-connected if the size of the smallest subset of vertices such that the graph becomes disconnected if you delete them is k.
If the vertex v that i delete from the graph isn't contained in the subset of vertex that if deleted disconnects the graph, how the graph becomes k-1-connected?

Comment: According to your definition, the statement you're trying to prove is false. Your definition is not the standard definition. Did you quote it exactly from your book?

Comment: According to the usual definition, a graph is $k$-vertex-connected if its vertex connectivity is **greater than or equal to** $k.$ It follows that a graph which is $k$-connected is also $(k-1)$-connected.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $S$ is a vertex set with $k-2$ vertices in $G\setminus\{v\}$. We want to prove that $(G - \{v\})\setminus S$ is still connected. Now assume for a contradiction that $(G - \{v\})\setminus S$ is not connected, say, there are $2$ components $A$, $B$ in $(G - \{v\})\setminus S$.  Consider that in $G$, the vertex $v$ is not in $S$, and $G$ is $k$-connected, which means that $v$ must be in $A$ or $B$ or connecting both $A$ and $B$. If $v$ is in $A$ and not in $B$, then $G\setminus S$ must be disconnected, and likewise if $v$ is in $B$ and not in $A$.

Consider if $v$ is in both $A$ and $B$, then in $G\setminus S$, $v$ is a cut-vertex.  So, together with $S$ (that is, $S \cup \{v\}$) it will form a vertex cut-set of size $k-2+1=k-1$ in $G$, contradicting our assumption that $G$ is $k$-connected.